# ios rotate image and zoom, so it fits original frame like in instagram

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, crop, transformation

In instagram when you rotate image it zooms, so you cannot see those angled corners. Thats perfect.

This topic is discussed here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61005/resizing-a-rectangle-to-always-fit-into-its-unrotated-space

I wonder if there is any out-of-box solution, some library that would include this function.

I know how to rotate or zoom image. I just don't know how much shall be the zoom after rotation according to the aspect ratio and angle.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any library, but the following methods should provide what you need.  Assume that you have a view of size `contentSize`, that you want to rotate through `angle` radians and scale to completely fill (with no "empty" corners) a view of size `containerSize`.  The first method below will return (as a `double`) the scale factor you should apply.

For completeness, the second method below will provide the scaling factor if you wish to rotate a view of size `contentSize` through `angle` radians and scale it to ensure if fits completely within the `containerSize` (so none of its corners extend beyond the edges).

Both methods assume that the two views have the same centre.

```
-(double)scaleToFill:(CGSize)containerSize withSize:(CGSize)contentSize atAngle:(double)angle {
    double theta = fabs(angle - 2*M_PI*truncf(angle/M_PI/2) - M_PI);
    if (theta > M_PI_2) {
        theta = fabs(M_PI - theta);
    }
    double h = contentSize.height;
    double H = containerSize.height;
    double w = contentSize.width;
    double W = containerSize.width;
    double scale1 = (H*cos(theta) + W*sin(theta))/h;
    double scale2 = (H*sin(theta) + W*cos(theta))/w;
    double scaleFactor = MAX(scale1, scale2);
    return scaleFactor;
}

-(double)scaleToFit:(CGSize)contentSize atAngle:(double)angle withinSize:(CGSize)containerSize {
    double theta = fabs(angle - 2*M_PI*truncf(angle/M_PI/2) - M_PI);
    if (theta > M_PI_2) {
        theta = fabs(M_PI - theta);
    }
    double h = contentSize.height;
    double H = containerSize.height;
    double w = contentSize.width;
    double W = containerSize.width;
    double scale1 = H/(h*cos(theta) + w*sin(theta));
    double scale2 = W/(h*sin(theta) + w*cos(theta));
    double scaleFactor = MIN(scale1, scale2);
    return scaleFactor;
}
```

You might use these with something like:

```
double scaleFactor = [self scaleToFill:self.containerView.bounds.size withSize:self.rotatedView.bounds.size atAngle:self.currentAngle];
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.currentAngle);
CGAffineTransform scaledRotation = CGAffineTransformScale(rotation, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
self.rotatedView.transform = scaledRotation;
```

Comment: That's a great algorithm, however, it seems to fail with an angle between π and 3π/2 (180° and 270°), where the scale goes negative. Do you possibly know why @pbasdf

Comment: @Zappel not sure, and I thought I had tested every quadrant.  But I'll look into it.

Comment: @Zappel Have just tested, and the scale seems to be positive for all positive angles, but it does go wrong for some negative angles.  Are your angles negative?  While I work out a fix, can you use fabs(angle) in the method call?